# Difference between get_template_directory_uri() and upload images to wordpress site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image

I'm working with WordPress and I just want to understand the difference between uploading an image in your media folder on your WordPress dashboard in the media folder, and use the `get_template_directory_uri();` to retrieve the theme directory and display images you have stored in your image folder like so:

`<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/image.png">`

Are there any of these solution that is better than the other?

thank you

Comment: Generaly, there is no difference. BUT you should store your image by its purpose. If it is part of template, it should be stored in template (if you remove template, file will also deleted), if you use it in content, then in the media folder, so you can change template and your image will be not deleted. Also if more users have acces to media library and you store the images from template here, this users can delete it and your template will not be complete.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Thanks for your answer

Comment: But doesn't all images being stored in the uploads folder?

Comment: Template images no. The should by in the template folder. So if you delete template, all the template parts, including images (that you dont need anymore), will be deleted. If you store them in uploads folder, after template deleting, they stay there for no reason.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be thinking in terms of **Is my content / resources static or dynamic?**

If the resource is part of the theme (ie. static), you are best to use:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/image.png">
```

If it is part of the content and can be changed by a WordPress user, then use the media uploads. An alternative is to use an options framework to allow the user to change static resources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is `get_template_directory_uri()` point directly to the current active template not to media folder. That's why called **template directory**.